# how to select a consecutive rows that satisfy a condition in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns, the first column is the RecordTime and the second column is the corresponding measure.
I want to select the first 3 hours interval with each measure > 150, and then calculate the SUM, AVG, MIN and MAX for the selected interval.
how can I do this ?

```
RecordTime           Measure
----------------------------
11/11/2015 11:46:00 253.3333
11/11/2015 11:47:00 241.792
11/11/2015 11:48:00 300.768
11/11/2015 11:49:00 277.1893
11/11/2015 11:50:00 301.2267
11/11/2015 11:51:00 332.208
11/11/2015 11:52:00 271.52
11/11/2015 11:53:00 280.9067
11/11/2015 11:54:00 275.7227
11/11/2015 11:55:00 214.992
11/11/2015 11:56:00 235.4507
11/11/2015 11:57:00 279.3013
11/11/2015 11:58:00 407.136
11/11/2015 11:59:00 553.1573
11/11/2015 12:00:00 519.0667
11/11/2015 12:01:00 431.8507
11/11/2015 12:02:00 501.0027
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  `SQL Server`, `MySQL`, `Oracle`, something else...?

Comment: Sorry, I am using SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what DBMS, but most DBMS have common table expressions (CTE) and date functions.

The CTE finds the first interval that satisfies your criteria (first 3 hour, all measures > 150). The final select provides you with your statistics

```
  with interval as (    
      select
         Min(recordTime) [Start],
      from [YourTable] T1
      where not exists
      (
         select 1
         from [YourTable] T2
         where 
           T2.RecordTime >= T1.RecordTime and
           T2.RecordTime < dateadd(hh, 3, T1.RecordTime) and
           T2.Measure > 150
      )    
   )
   select  
       Min(recordTime) as IntervalStart,
       SUM(Measure), AVG(Measure), MIN(Measure), MAX(Measure)
   from [YourTable]
   where 
     RecordTime >= (select [Start] from interval) and
     RecordTime < (select dateadd(hh, 3, [Start]) from interval)
```

Comment: What should be [start] in the query ? Thanks

Comment: @user1433645 - If you want to avoid using CTE's (with as...)  you can copy the whole expression into `interval` part